# One LaTex file generates two PDF files

Tags: latex

right now I'm writing a tex-template and I was wondering if it's possible to generate two PDF files while compiling one single LaTex file. Speaking more clearly, I'm writing a exercise sheet and one PDF file should include only the exercises and the other file should include the exercises as well as the solutions for it. Right now I'm working with

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\providetoggle{solution}
\settoggle{solution}{false}
```

where solution = false means, that no solution is shown in the PDF file.
I'd like to have one PDF file which is called e.g. "Exercise Sheet 1" where solution is false and another PDF file names "Solution for Exercise Sheet 1" where solution = true.

Don't know if this is even possible?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: have a look if https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=583 helps

Comment: Actually I'm not quite sure. Maybe the third answer could work, but I don't know how to implement it in TexMaker.

Comment: Switch to texstudio - it is basically a fork of texmaker, but with lots of useful additions, amongst others magic comments